# Calling functions from a c++ DLL in Delphi

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, delphi-7

I created a new c++ DLL project in VS2010 that exposes 1 function

```
#include "stdafx.h"    
#define DllImport   extern "C" __declspec( dllimport )
#define DllExport   extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )    
DllExport int DoMath( int a, int b) {
    return a + b ; 
}
```

I then created a C++ application with VS2010 to test this DLL. The test application build in VS2010 could call the c++ DLL and get the expected result.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <windows.h>

typedef int (*DoMath)(int, int) ; 
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    HMODULE hMod = LoadLibrary ("exampleDLL.dll");
    if (NULL != hMod) {
        DoMath mf1 = (DoMath) GetProcAddress(hMod,"DoMath");
        if( mf1 != NULL ) {
            printf ("DoMath(8,7)==%d \n", mf1(8,7) );   
        } else {
            printf ("GetProcAddress Failed \n");
        }
        FreeLibrary(hMod);
    } else { 
        printf ("LoadLibrary failed\n");
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Next I attempted to build a new project in Delphi 7 to call this C++ DLL. I used [this tutorial](http://www.drbob42.com/delphi/headconv.htm) to help me build the new project.

```
unit Unit1;
interface
uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TmyFunction = function(X,Y: Integer):Integer;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    Edit1: TEdit;
    procedure FormShow(Sender: TObject);
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
    hDll: THandle;
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;
  fDoMath : TmyFunction;

implementation
{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.FormShow(Sender: TObject);
begin
  hDll := LoadLibrary('exampleDLL.dll');
   if HDll >= 32 then { success }
   begin
     fDoMath := GetProcAddress(hDll, 'DoMath');
   end
   else
     MessageDlg('Error: could not find exampleDLL.DLL', mtError, [mbOk], 0)
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var i: Integer;
begin
 i := fDoMath(2,3);
 edit1.Text := IntToStr(i);
end;
end.
```

The result from the Delphi 7 project is *6155731* When I expected *5*. I checked the binary of the result thinking it might have something to do with a data type but it looks random to me. When I recompile/rerun the application it gets the same result every time.

I do not know a lot about Delphi this is the first time I have deal with it and i find it confusing.

Any suggestion on what to check next?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to specify the calling convention, which in this case is `cdecl`:

```
TMyFunction = function(X, Y: Integer): Integer; cdecl;
```

Your code uses the default Delphi calling convention which is `register` and passes parameters through registers. The `cdecl` calling convention passes parameters on the stack and so this mis-match explains why communications between the two modules fail.

---

Some more comments:

The failure mode for `LoadLibrary` is to return `NULL`, that is `0`. Check that rather than the return value being `>=32`.

It's simpler to use implicit linking to import this function. Replace all the `LoadLibrary` and `GetProcAddress` code with this simple declaration:

```
function DoMath(X, Y: Integer): Integer; cdecl; external 'exampleDLL.dll';
```

The system loader will resolve this import when your executable starts so you don't have to worry about the details of linking.

Answer (score 0):

On RAD Studio Berlin, using CLANG compiler for the C++ part, a cdecl function which is extern "C" will have its name prepended with an underscore, traditional unix "C" style.  The above code doesn't work in this case, but use the name attribute of the external declaration to fix the problem:

function DoMath(X, Y: Integer): Integer; cdecl; external 'exampleDLL.dll' name '_DoMath';

Not tried it with other compilers, so it might be a general issue with cdecl.  The Windows API does not use cdecl, but uses same calling convention as Delphi so, for example, the Winapi.Windows declarations of DLL functions do not have the underscore added.

Same true if using GetProcAddress, the correct call is GetProcAddress(hDLL, '_DoMath');  otherwise nil is returned.

Hope this helps anyone struggling to get Delphi talking to C++.

Comment: I have Delphi RAD 10.2 and the Sum(a+b+c) works fine,  with `int __declspec(dllexport) __stdcall calcsum(int a, int b, int c){ return a +b +c; }` in the DLL. The dyn call is: ` calcsum := GetProcAddress(hmod, 'calcsum');  ` and works fine also. BUT I HAVE really problems in getting a char* ( or string) of the function return. Do you know why and could you give me a advice, please?