# Calling a callback function in Delphi from a C++ DLL

Tags: c++, delphi, dll, delphi-7

I have a C++ DLL that I wrote that has a single exposed function, that takes a function pointer (callback function) as a parameter.

```
#define DllExport   extern "C" __declspec( dllexport )

DllExport bool RegisterCallbackGetProperty( bool (*GetProperty)( UINT object_type, UINT object_instnace, UINT property_identifer, UINT device_identifier, float * value ) ) {
    // Do something. 
}
```

I want to be able to call this exposed C++ DLL function from within a Delphi application and register the callback function to be used at a future date. But I am unsure of how to make a function pointer in Delphi that will work with the exposed C++ DLL function.

I have the [Delphi application calling a simple exposed c++ DLL functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10405991/calling-functions-from-a-c-dll-in-delphi/10455039#10455039) from the help I got in this question.

I am building the C++ DLL and I can change its parameters if needed.

My questions are:

- How to I create a function pointer in Delphi
- How to I correctly call the exposed C++ DLL function from within a Delphi application so that the C++ DLL function can use the function pointer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Declare a function pointer in Delphi by declaring a function type. For example, the function type for your callback could be defined like this:

```delphi
type
  TGetProperty = function(object_type, object_instnace, property_identifier, device_identifier: UInt; value: PSingle): Boolean; cdecl;
```

Note the calling convention is `cdecl` because your C++ code specified no calling convention, and cdecl is the usual default calling convention for C++ compilers.

Then you can use that type to define the DLL function:

```delphi
function RegisterCallbackGetProperty(GetProperty: TGetProperty): Boolean; cdecl; external 'dllname';
```

Replace `'dllname'` with the name of your DLL.

To call the DLL function, you should first have a Delphi function with a signature that matches the callback type. For example:

```delphi
function Callback(object_type, object_instnace, property_identifier, device_identifier: UInt; value: PSingle): Boolean cdecl;
begin
  Result := False;
end;
```

Then you can call the DLL function and pass the callback just as you would any other variable:

```delphi
RegisterCallbackGetProperty(Callback);
```