# Variable required error (Delphi) - How to take the address of a procedure?

Tags: delphi, pointers

Using Delphi 7 here. When I take the address of a procedure (with the purpose of sending this method address to an external C++ DLL as a callback) the Delphi 7 compiler reports `Variable required`. Why? How do you take the address of a method with or without a parameter list?

Here's my simplified code which shows the compiler error.

```
// ...

type
  PTProcedureCallback = ^TProcedureCallback;
  TProcedureCallback = procedure() of object;

  // ...

  TTestCallback = class
    constructor Create();
    procedure MyCallback();
  end;

    //...

implementation
  constructor TTestCallback.Create();
  var
    pCallback: PTProcedureCallback;
  begin
    // Constructor
    inherited;

    // Test callback
    pCallback := @MyCallback;   // <- [Error] Variable required
  end;

  procedure TTestCallback.MyCallback();
  begin
    // Do something
  end;
end;
```

Comment: You can't pass a method pointer (a method of a class) to a C++ DLL, because it has an implicit `Self` reference passed along with it that the C++ DLL doesn't understand. The `procedure of object` indicates that it will have that `Self` reference. (Not the answer to the problem here, but it will save you time in the future trying to figure out why it doesn't work anyway once you figure this out.)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need `PTProcedureCallback` at all, as `TProcedureCallback` is already a pointer type.

```pascal
constructor TTestCallback.Create();
var
  pCallback: TProcedureCallback;
begin
  // Constructor
  inherited;
  // Test callback
  pCallback := MyCallback;
end;
```

That being said, you can't use a `procedure of object` as a C/C++ callback, unless the C/C++ code was written in C++Builder specifically, and is actually expecting a `procedure of object` via the `__closure` compiler extension. If not, you will not be able to use a *non-static* class method as the callback. However, if the callback allows you to pass in a user-defined value, you can use that to pass in your object's `Self` pointer so your callback can access its non-static members.

Also, your `TProcedureCallback` is using Delphi's default `register` calling convention (`__fastcall` in C++Builder), which does not exist in non-C++Builder compilers. Only `cdecl` and `stdcall` are portable calling conventions.

Comment: Thanks Remy. I'm busy working through that at the moment. If I just change the code as you suggest, though, I still get the same `Variable required` error. I'm actually trying to answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56707554 in which another question has been marked as a duplicate. I can get the C++ DLL calling my method when I specify no parameters, but when I try an integer parameter, the parameter becomes garbled. The C++ DLL is being built in Visual Studio and I've tried both `__cdecl` and `__stdcall` calling conventions.

Comment: Then try simply `pCallback := MyCallback;` instead (drop the `@`).

Comment: Looks like my problem was as you stated in the 2nd paragraph: I'm trying to provide a `non-static` class method as a C/C++ callback. When I made the methods static (changing `procedure TTestCallback.MyCallback` to `procedure MyCallback`) it starting working. So much to learn...thanks Remy!